# wait for click before losing focus

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a search dropdown which shows suggestions when a search input gets focus.
The problem is I have code such that the dropdown closes when this input loses focus. This is how I want it but the problem is that as soon as I click on any suggestion, the box closes before the click is registered for that suggestion.

My code:-
html:-

```
<div id="demo-2">
 <input
   type="search"
   placeholder="Search By Title, Author"
 />
 <div class="autocomplete">
   <mdb-card *ngFor="let book of books" (click)="logger(book.id)">
     <!--some code-->
   </mdb-card>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:-

```
#demo-2 input[type="search"]:focus {
  width: 275px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;

  ~ .autocomplete {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.autocomplete {
  height: 350px;
  width: 275px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

ts (excerpt):-

```
  logger(id) {
    console.log(id); 
  }
```

Been at it for more than a day. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can delay the closing of the dropdown by wrapping the trigger inside of a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable `isVisible` in your TS:

```
isVisible = false;

logger(id) {
  console.log(id);
  isVisible = false;
}

hide() {
  isVisible = false;
}

inputClicked() {
  isVisible = true;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="demo-2">
 <input
   type="search"
   placeholder="Search By Title, Author" (focusout)="hide()"
 />
 <div class="autocomplete" [ngStyle]="{'visibility':isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
   <mdb-card *ngFor="let book of books" (click)="logger(book.id)">
     <!--some code-->
   </mdb-card>
 </div>
</div>
```

Remove `visibility` property from your CSS.

Comment: But this won't hide box  if user clicks outside the suggestion box

Answer (score 0):

~.autocomplete will apply properties on element's siblings. So rather than applying it on div, try to apply it on mdb-card